# Positioning squares on a circle with minimum diameter

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

Given *n* squares with edge length *l*, how can I determine the minimum radius *r* of the circle so that I can distribute all squares evenly along the perimeter of the circle without them overlapping? (Constraint: the first square will always be positioned at 12 o'clock.)

Followup question: how can I place *n* identical rectangles with height *h* and width *w*?

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [n3rd.org](http://pub.n3rd.org/circle.png))</sub>

Comment: What's the context?  Is this homework?

Comment: Are the squares always "straight up and down"? And what does "distribute evenly" mean in this context?

Comment: Sounds like someones homework to me.

Comment: @will: no, it's for some sort of popup menu that will center around the mouse cursor

@pst: yes.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask this on MathOverflow. SO is for _programming_ questions.

Comment: well, i do need to implement the algorithm. unless the solution can be expressed as a simple formula (which i don't know yet)

Comment: do the rectangles have to be on the edge of the circle?

Comment: @louis: yes. the centers of the rectangles have to be on the edge of the circle.

Comment: I think I got it :) See my updated answer.

Comment: @Oded - this is definitely NOT a MathOverflow question - it seems perfectly legit here to me, as it's not homework (and even homework would be legit were it tagged correctly)

Comment: @n3rd: maybe it's a good idea to put it somewhere in the question statement

Comment: @Will Dean - the question as posted has no programming elements to it, but only an abstract mathematical/geometric problem.

Comment: @Oded - well, that may be true, but that's certainly not enough to make it a MathOverflow question.

Comment: @Will Dean - it certainly is enough to make it off topic for SO, unless the programming aspect of it is clarified.

Comment: @Oded - I'm with Will on this, and I think this is supported by the best answer (Carl's) being an iterative solution, an algorithm, rather than just a formula

Comment: The question asks for an algorithm, which implies it being for a program of some sort. So it certainly has programming elements to it.

Comment: @Nick: I'm afraid I've killed your argument by stating the solution in a form that could be presented as a formula (by someone more clever than myself). But I agree that it's a question on how to solve a concrete programming problem. When we started out, I wasn't aware that there was a "mathematical" solution, and the OP was definitely correct to ask for help here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<s>There may be a mathematically clever way to do this, but I wouldn't know.
I think it's complicated a bit by the fact that the geometry is different for every different number of squares; for 4 it's a rhombus, for 5 it's a pentagon and so on.</s>

What I'd do is place those squares on a 1 unit circle (much too small, I know, bear with me) distributed equally on it. That's easy enough, just subtend (divide) your 360 degrees by the number of squares. Then just test all your squares for overlap against their neighbors; if they overlap, increase the radius.

You can make this procedure less stupid than it sounds by using an intelligent algorithm to approach the right size. I'm thinking of something like Newton's algorithm: Given two successive guesses, of which one is too small and one is too big, your next guess needs to be the average of those two.

You can iterate down to any precision you like. Stop whenever the distance between guesses is smaller than some arbitrary small margin of error.

**EDIT** I have a better solution:

I was thinking about what to tell you if you asked "how will I know if squares overlap?" This gave me an idea on how to calculate the circle size exactly, in one step:

Place your squares on a much-too-small circle. You know how: Calculate the points on the circle where your 360/n angles intersect it, and put the center of the square there. Actually, you don't need to place squares yet, the next steps only require midpoints.

To calculate the minimum distance of a square to its neighbor: Calculate the difference in X and the difference in Y of the midpoints, and take the minimum of those. The X's and Y's are actually just cosines and sines on the circle.

You'll want the minimum of *any* square against its neighbor (clockwise, say). So you need to work your way around the circle to find the very smallest one.

The minimum (X or Y) distance between the squares needs to become 1.0 . So just take the reciprocal of the minimum distance and multiply the circle's size by that. Presto, your circle is the right size.

**EDIT**

Without losing generality, I think it's possible to nail my solution down a bit so it's close to coding. Here's a refinement:

- Assume the squares have size 1, i.e. each side has a length of 1 unit. In the end, your boxes will surely be larger than 1 pixel but it's just a matter of scaling.
- Get rid of the corner cases:

  ```
  if (n < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  if (n == 2) return 0.5; // 2 squares will fit exactly on a circle of radius 0.5
  ```
- Start with a circle size `r` of 0.5, which will surely be too small for any number of squares > 2.

  ```
  r = 0.5;
  dmin = 1.0; // start assuming minimum distance is fine
  a = 2 * PI / n;
  for (p1 = 0.0; p1 <= PI; p1+=a) { // starting with angle 0, try all points till halfway around
     // (yeah, we're starting east, not north. doesn't matter)
     p2 = p1 + a; // next point on the circle 
     dx = abs(r * cos(p2) - r * cos(p1))
     dy = abs(r * sin(p2) - r * sin(p1))
     dmin = min(dmin, dx, dy)
  }

  r = r / dmin;
  ```

---

**EDIT**

I turned this into real Java code and got something quite similar to this to run. Code and results here: http://ideone.com/r9aiu

I created graphical output using GnuPlot. I was able to create simple diagrams of boxes arranged in a circle by cut-and-pasting the point sets from the output into a data file and then running

```
plot '5.dat' with boxxyerrorbars
```

The `.5`'s in the file serve to size the boxes... lazy but working solution. The .5 is applied to both sides of the center, so the boxes end up being exactly 1.0 in size.

Alas, **my algorithm doesn't work**. It makes the radii far too large, thus placing the boxes much further apart than necessary. Even scaling down by a factor of 2 (could have been a mistake to use 0.5 in some places) didn't help.

<s>Sorry, I give up. Maybe my approach can be salvaged, but it doesn't work the way I had though it would. :(</s>

---

**EDIT**

I hate giving up. I was about to leave my PC when I thought of a way to salvage my algorithm:

The algorithm was adjusting the *smaller* of the X or Y distances to be at least 1. It's easy to demonstrate that's just plain silly. When you have a lot of boxes then at the eastern and western edges of the circle you have boxes stacked almost directly on top of each other, with their X's very close to one another but they are saved from touching by having just enough Y distance between them.

So... to make this work, you must scale the **maximum** of dx and dy to be (for all cases) at least the radius (or was it double the radius?).

Corrected code is here: <s>http://ideone.com/EQ03g</s> http://ideone.com/VRyyo

Tested again in GnuPlot, it produces beautiful little circles of boxes where sometimes just 1 or 2 boxes are exactly touching. **Problem solved!** :)

[image]
[image]

(These images are wider than they are tall because GnuPlot didn't know I wanted proportional layout. Just imagine the whole works squeezed into a square shape :) )

Comment: sounds good! i'll give it a go later today and if everything checks out your answer will be accepted, sir! :)

Comment: @carl, having problems following. a) if circle is much-too-small then squares intersect, i.e. the minimum distance between squares is 0 b)the minimum distance between midpoints is not zero, it is positive number, but I fail to see the relation between that and diameter c) last paragraph 'distance between the circles'?

Comment: @Unreason: Last thing first, you caught a typo. s/circles/squares/. Corrected. (a) to see if squares intersect, it is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition that the distance on either the X or Y axis between their midpoints is less or equal to the length of a square's side (only works for equally sized squares). So you don't have to bother checking if parts of the squares' perimeters overlap, you just make sure midpoints not too close.

Comment: @Unreason: (b) if you position your squares on your circle and find a pair of midpoints that are only 50% of the "touching" distance apart in either X or Y, then you need to double the size of the circle and you'll be done. i.e. you make the circle bigger in inverse proportion to how much too small that minimum distance is.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not following. When the squares are initially placed, they are distributed evenly across the circle. Thus, the minimum distance between a square and its neighbours is the same for all squares.
Also, where does the size of the squares come into play? If two squars are at the same height (or width), their difference in x (or y) is 0, what now? Maybe you can elaborate a little bit :)

Comment: @n3rd Nope, your first sentence is incorrect. If the squares were little circles, then indeed their distances would be independent of their orientation. But as they are squares and always oriented the same way, their corners stick out in different ways depending on where they are on the circle, i.e. they are not symmetric.

Comment: @n3rd: My pseudo-coded example may make things a bit clearer too. I'm almost ready to write code for this anyway.

Comment: I've started doing this in Java. First result here: http://ideone.com/WgAET . I need to output graphics, though. Hang on.

Comment: @carl: Oh, I see. I was thinking you were referring to the distance between the square's midpoints. My bad.

Comment: @Carl, that was my point, the scaling factor is not directly proportional to the distance, but you are on the right track and have to find the factor to scale by. I'll try to give it a try.

Comment: Sorry about all the breathless reports. After some tweaking, I now have it working correctly; I can produce diagrams showing angularly equispaced boxes with some of them exactly touching.

Comment: @Unreason: Now I can state with confidence: The scaling factor needs to be exactly the factor by which, in the worst case, the maximum (X or Y) distance between two adjacent boxes is too small.

Comment: @Carl, I've put in the answer, but it is only descriptive for now.

Comment: +1 I agree, it is directly proportional; I've taken a different path by solving for l and it boils down to the same formulas as you have. One note - in your source you comment `start assuming minimum distance dMin = 1.0`; but it is actually maximum distance (dMin in all solutions is < 1.0). Not a bug, but got me running in circles for a while trying to understand the code.

Comment: @Carl How do I adapt Your program to work with arbitrary edge lengths of the rects?

Comment: @Dave, here's my contribution - I modified Carls solution to work with h x w rectangles :) http://ideone.com/eP1oX . However, this will show you one thing - even for h/w = 3 (which is a small menu, I guess) you will not get evenly spaced menu items - the assumption that you should place the center of rectangles on i*(2*pi)/n is flawed (if you want it too look nice) and I think you will want to reevaluate your requirements.

Comment: @Dave, Unreason: Hehe, the problem is a lot easier when h == w! I don't have a very clear idea of how to extend it to rectangles in an aesthetically pleasing way. I think I'd generate a new set of angles by stretching an equal-angled circle to the proportions of the rectangle and then mapping the angles back to the circle; and then using Unreason's algorithm to size the circle.

Comment: @Dave, also the algorithm might have problems with extremely high rectangles at pi/2 (and 3*pi/2) or extremely wide at 0, pi (also depending on the number of rectangles) because only the two consecutive rectangles are checked, and in the the above cases it is possible for noncosecutive rectangles to intersect when consecutive only touch.

Comment: @Dave, like your idea of stretch and shrink, but I think that visually the best would be to look for a solution where the distance between rectangles is equal (or in another words if the requirement for the equality of angles is removed there exists a circle with lesser r; and algorithm to find it)

Comment: @Carl, `set size square` makes aspect ratio 1:1 in gnuplot

Answer (score 4):

I would calculate an upper bound of the minimum radius, by working with circles enclosing the squares instead of with the squares themselves.

My calculation results in:

Rmin <= X / (sqrt(2) * sin (180/N) )

Where:
X is the square side length, and N is the required number of squares.

I assume that the circles are positioned such that their centers fall on the big circle's circumference.

-- EDIT --

Using the idea of Dave in the comment below, we can also calculate a nice lower bound, by considering the circles to be inside the squares (thus having radius X/2). This bound is:

Rmin >= X / (2 * sin (180/N) )

Comment: using this upper bound why not advance and make a binary search for the smallest radius that causes no rects to intersect? Runtime O(n * log Rmin)

Comment: @Dave followup: One can get a lower bound by using circles that lie inside the rects rather than enclose them. Now find the correct radius between Rmin & Rmax with binary search -> O(n * log(Rmax-Rmin))

Comment: @Dave: Nice idea, especially with both bounds. Please ignore my last comment.

Comment: Heh, after seeing a comment stating that n3rd was putting together a (radial) menu, I started thinking that using circles to display the menu items would look better than squares (Neverwinter Nights, anyone?), and this meshes quite well with that, too.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted, the problem of positioning n points equally spaced round the circumference of a circle is trivial.  The (not-terribly) difficult part of the problem is to figure out the radius of the circle needed to give a pleasing layout of the squares.  I suggest you follow one of the other answers and think of the squares being inside a circular 'buffer' big enough to contain the square and enough space to satisfy your aesthetic requirements.  Then check the formula for the [chord length](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html) between the centres of neighbouring squares.  Now you have the angle, at the centre of the circle, subtended by the chord between square centres, and can easily compute the radius of the circle from the trigonometry of a triangle.

And, as to your follow up question: I suggest that you work out the problem for squares of side length `min(h,w)` on a circle, then transform the squares to rectangles and the circle to an ellipse with eccentricity h/w (or w/h).

Answer (score 0):

You start with an arbitrary circle (e.g., with a diameter of `(* n l)`) and position the squares evenly on the circumference.  Then you go through each pair of adjacent squares and:

- calculate the straight line connecting their mid points,
- calculate the intersection of this line with the intervening square sides (M1 and M2 are the mid points, S1 and S2 the corresponding intersections with the square side:

  ```
                  S2         S1
  M1--------------*----------*---------------M2

  ------------------------
  |                      |
  |                      |
  |                      |
  |                      |
  |          M1          |
  |           \          |
  |            \         |
  |      -------*------- +--------
  |      |       \       |       |
  |      |        \      |       |
  -------+---------*------       |
         |          \            |
         |           M2          |
         |                       |
         |                       |
         |                       |
         |                       |
         -------------------------
  ```
- calculate the scale factor you would need to make S1 and S2 fall together (simply the ratio of the sum of M1-S1 and S2-M2 to M1-M2), and

finally scale the circle by the maximum of the found scale factors.

*Edit:*  This is the exact solution.  However, a little thought can optimize this further for speed:

- You only need to do this for the squares closest to 45° (if *n* is even) resp. 45° and 135° (if *n* is odd; actually, you might prove that only one of these is necessary).
- For large *n*, the optimal spacing of the squares on the circle will quickly approach the length of a diagonal of a square.  You could thus precompute the scaling factors for a few small *n* (up to a dozen or so), and then have a good enough approximation with the diagonal.

Comment: No, I don't think that yields an optimal solution. You are asking for a scale where the corners are just touching. I discovered that this makes the circle much too large; it's only necessary for one set of sides (either the horizontal or vertical) to touch.

Comment: No, I did not write nor mean the corners.  I am writing about the intersection of the connecting line between the centres of two neighbouring squares with the squares' edges.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz:  I added a rough sketch.

Comment: @Svante From my point of view You overlook that, when scaling down (reducing the radius of the circle), the relative position between the rects changes too and therefore invalidates the values S2 and S1.

Comment: When scaling down, the relative position does _not_ change.  Think about it:  the angle of the line connecting the mid points is only dependent on _n_, the number of squares.

Comment: I think I stand corrected. Thanks to your diagram, this looks like it could well work.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

To find the relation between the radius r and length l let's analyze dimensionless representation

- get the centres on a circle (x1,y1)..(xn,yn)
- from each center get lower right corner of the i-th square and upper left corner of the i+1-th square
- the two points should either have equal x or equal y, whichever yields smaller l
- procedure should be repeated for each center and the one that yields smallest l is the final solution.

This is the optimal solution and can be solved it terms of r = f(l).
The solution can be adapted to rectangles by adjusting the formula for xLR[i] and yUL[i+1].

Will try to give some pseudo code.

EDIT:
There's a bug in the procedure, lower right and upper left are not necessary closest points for two neighbouring squares/rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you solved the problem for 3 or 4 squares.

If you have *n* >= 5 squares, and position one square at the top of the circle, you'll have another square fall into the first quadrant of a cartesian plane concentric with your circle.

The problem is then to find a radius *r* for the circle such that the left side of the circle next to the top one, and the right side of the top circle do not 'cross' each other.

The *x* coordinate of the right side of the top circle is *x1* = *L*/2, where *L* is the side of a square. The *x* coordinate of the left side of the circle next to the top one is *x2* = *r* cos *a* - *L*/2, where *r* is the radius and *a* is the angle between each pair of square centres (*a* = 360/*n* degrees).

So we need to solve *x1* <= *x2*, which leads to

***r* >= *L* / cos *a*.**

*L* and *a* are known, so we're done :-)